# How does the Macro work 'REGISTER_OP("ZeroOut")' in Adding a New Op in Tensorflow?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, macros

I am going through the documentation of Tensorflow on 'Adding a new op'.
I understand how macros work in C++ but I am not able to understand the syntax that has been used.
The code given is:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

REGISTER_OP("ZeroOut")
    .Input("to_zero: int32")
    .Output("zeroed: int32")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
      return Status::OK();
    });
```

I am confused with the implementation of '**REGISTER_OP("ZeroOut")**' and followed by the '.' operator. (I understand that the '.' operator can be used for accessing members of a class object but not sure why it has been used here.)

Could anyone please tell me if this is just a variation of some implementation of Macros?

Link for TF documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op
TIA.

Comment: Please add your code example as code and not as image.

Comment: Added the code. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the reference code in `op.h` that [`REGISTER_OP` macro](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h) is in, each of these methods below returns `*this`, that means the chaining of

- `.Input`
- `.Output`
- `.SetShapeFn()`

is a [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) called [`Builder`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), which is to

> > provide a flexible solution to separate the construction of a complex object from its representation.

This design pattern is widely used in [unit testing](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/07/15/flexible-and-expressive-unit-tests-with-the-builder-pattern/) as well.